# Code for matching date Pattern

Tags: java, date

I  have a scenario where I  get the date value from the xml and the date value from the website. I am able to retrieve the results, But now I need to compare the format of the retrieved results whether it is in 'MM YYYY'  format or not ? How can i do that ? i have to check the format in String manner ie for e.g Apr 2010 but not 04 2010

Please can anyone of you help me ??

Comment: By the way, check out the [`YearMonth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class of the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SimpleDate {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    String strDate = sdf.format(date);   
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/yyyy");
    strDate = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(strDate);

  }
}
```

Comment: where you declared `strDate`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expresson, like this `(Jan|Feb|Mar...) d{4}`